# How to get a piece of an json object with its parent node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I just get a part of my object including its parent node?

complete string objet:

```
var big = '{ "OFFLINE": { "more"  : "content"  }, 
             "ONLINE":  { "more1" : "content1" },
             "EXTRA":   { "more2" : "content2" }  }';
alert( JSON.parse( big ) );
```

I want to get in a new object:

```
var part = '{ "OFFLINE": { "more"  : "content"  }}';
```

I have no success with : `JSON.parse( big ).OFFLINE`

because it is containing: `'{ "more"  : "content"  }'`

instead of`'{ "OFFLINE": { "more"  : "content"  }}'`

Comment: Yea, what you want is not how JSON or JavaScript objects work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) convert oject to string.
Try this:

```js
var big = '{ "OFFLINE": { "more"  : "content"  }, "ONLINE":  { "more1" : "content1" },"EXTRA":   { "more2" : "content2" }  }';
var newObject = {
  OFFLINE: JSON.parse(big).OFFLINE
}
alert(JSON.stringify(newObject));
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have now - `JSON.parse( big ).OFFLINE` is exactly what you need, you just need to wrap it in a parent object, if that's how you need it:

```
var obj = {
    OFFLINE: JSON.parse(big).OFFLINE
};
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6gqzL9Lc/)